# Selenium2: Deleting ALL cookies, even ones not related to the current domain

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a test which needs to delete cookies from a number of domains when it starts up.  `driver.manage().deleteAllCookies()` seems to only delete cookies set by the domain you're currently on.

Is there a way to force the browser to clear all cookies?

Answer (score 0):

May be this post will point you in the right direction?

http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-capybara/browse_thread/thread/7d94606d2c2abaf

https://gist.github.com/474236

Comment: Thank Bhavani.  I'm using Java and Selenium grid 2 but I'll look for something similar to what you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You should use one profile if you want to delete all cookies. If every time selenium is creating new anonymous profile it is not possible to delete those cookies.