# How can I delete all cookies from all domains?

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Webdriver Wire Protocol doesn't contain a method for deleting all cookies from all domains. [It can only delete cookies from current domain](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#/session/%3asessionId/cookie).

I'd want to delete all cookies from all domains as AUT has integration with 3rd party sites that set cookies and I'd want to ensure clean state in the beginning of each test to improve ease of maintainability.

So I started to think about driver-specific ways to delete all cookies. I'm interested particularly in Firefox.

In Firefox it can be done by either:

- pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- writing Firefox extension that will allow to do it in one step

Do I miss something? Is there a cross-driver option to delete all cookies (from all domains)?

Comment: Similar question: [Selenium2: Deleting ALL cookies, even ones not related to the current domain](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7039003/841064)

Comment: Currently I do a workaround by visiting that another domain to delete cookies previously set by it

Answer (score -4):

There are several ways to accomplish this. This is how I normally implement the work in my frameworks.

When creating a new driver object (in this case ChromerDriver) set the ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION capability:

```
public WebDriver driver() {

    File driverServer = new File(WebDriverConfig.class.getClassLoader().getResource("webDrivers/chromedriver.exe").getFile());
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverServer.getAbsolutePath());
    DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.ForSeleniumServer.ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
    return new ChromeDriver();

}
```

Then at the beginning of each of my tests using TestNG's framework:

```
@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void setup() {

    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    // Do other stuff before each test executes

}
```

You can also delete only specific cookies by getting the cookies and finding the one you want and then removing that one.

`driver.manage().getCookies();`

I hope this helps you in finding a resolution to your issue.

Comment: `driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();` deletes cookies only from current domain (visible to current page). `getCookies` returns only cookies from current domain. That's why I asked question and repeated "from all domains" 3 times there